# Pyautogui click not clicking properly

Tags: python, click, bots

in this code:

```
temp = None
while temp == None:
    temp = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("Play_Button.PNG")

play_buttonx, play_buttony = pyautogui.center(temp)

pyautogui.click(play_buttonx, play_buttony, duration = 0.3)
```

The pointer heads to the center of the button and stops!

I tried the win32api + win32con, still it didn't work, I tried setting "clicks" to a different number, changing intervals, etc..., yet nothing works, once I touch my mousepad the button is clicked and the game starts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the game detects injected mouse clicks and key presses, so I need to bypass the injected flag.

Answer (score 0):

try replace `pyautogui.click(play_buttonx, play_buttony, duration = 0.3)`
with `pyautogui.click(play_buttonx, play_buttonny, clicks = 2, duration = 0.3)`
the first click should make python select the window then the second click should actually click the button.